# How do I add two separate text annotations to a single bar chart?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I have this plot -

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23])])
fig.show()
```

I want to add two different text annotations. I want to have one text annotation inside the bars that says "A", "B" and "C" and I want to have a second text annotation outside the bars that says "1", "2", "3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner annotations are realized with bar chart codes. Outside the bar chart, the annotation function can be used, but it is easier to use the text mode for scatter plots.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23], text=['A','B','C'], textposition='inside')])
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='text', x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23], text=['1','2','3'], textposition='top center', showlegend=False))

fig.update_yaxes(range=[0,25])
fig.show()
```

[image]